# How to print logs when I use command of docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to print error logs when I run command of `docker-compose up`

When I run command of `docker-compose up`, there is no error which can occurs in my web application

But when i run command of `docker-compose run web`, there is a error message which exactly i wanted.

this is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python zeus/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/zeus_test
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Is there a way to print error logs when I run command of `docker-compose up`?

---

## Edit

This is my minimal reproduction

https://github.com/RayKimEX/mydocker-compose

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run `docker-compose run web`, the database container doesn't start up together, maybe that's the reason you get error.

But anyway, if you need know what exact errors in servie `web` containers, I would run below commands to find error out.

```
docker-compose logs web
```

Or you only need logs with key word of `error`

```
docker-compose logs web |grep -i error
```

You can add `-f` to catch latest logs.

```
    -f, --follow        Follow log output.
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answering this question. I want to know more about this. If I can't get error message because the database container doesn't start up together, Could you tell me how to debug this exactly? I updated the question which contains my exactly same repository.

Comment: I mean 'debug' is how to 'prove' or 'know' that you mentioned